# A few questions on an underdetermined linear system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computer-science

Reading [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1710377) and trying to get a gasp of it, in the introduction section it talks about a linear system of equations which is $Y=DX$ where $D \in \mathbb R^{n\times K}$. The part I am trying to understand is as follows:

> if $n<K$ and $D$ is a full rank matrix, an infinite number of
> solutions are available for the problem, hence constraints on the
> solution must be set.

What I understand from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207636/can-an-underdetermined-system-have-a-unique-solution/207641#207641) is quite different from what they are claiming to be the case. My questions are:

- What is the condition $D$ being full rank doing? Why is it needed?
  Since we already know that's an underdetermined system and it has
  infinitely many solutions.
- Then it says we need to set constraints, but the answer I linked to states that we more constraints we will have more equations and the case would turn into a different one. Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

This equation has K unknowns and n conditions. Because $n \lt K$, it needs more constraints in order to have an  unique solution. Because D is full rank, so likely, it needs another $K-n$ independent constraints.